# What's the prevalence of pulsatile tinnitus?

Tags: tinnitus

In Baomin et al (2014) it is written that "Although prevalence of pulsatile tinnitus is merely 4%", with a citation to Liyanage et al (2006).

In Liyanage et al (2006) it is written that "Pulsatile sounds are reported in about 4 per cent of unselected patients with tinnitus". They cite Stouffer and Tyler (1990) in support of this claim. I can't access this Stouffer and Tyler (1990) paper.

Is there some other source which speaks to this question? I don't feel like I can trust a paper that cites a paper that cites some paper from 1990.

Ideally the paper would report on the prevalence for Caucasian adults in the west, but it need not necessarily be so specific.

Baomin, L., Xiangyu, C., Xinfeng, L., Sheng, L., Jun, W., Yongping, L., ... & Huimin, F. (2014). Interventionai Diagnosis and Treatment of Vasculogeneic Pulsatile Tinnitus. Journal of Otology, 9(1), 7-15.

Liyanage, S. H., Singh, A., Savundra, P., & Kalan, A. (2006). Pulsatile tinnitus. The Journal of Laryngology & Otology, 120(02), 93-97.

Stouffer, J. L., & Tyler, R. S. (1990). Characterization of tinnitus by tinnitus patients. Journal of Speech and Hearing Disorders, 55(3), 439-453.

Comment: Are you only interested in pulsatile tinnitus, our would something like [Davis et al (2007)](http://www.journalslibrary.nihr.ac.uk/hta/volume-11/issue-42#) which reported the prevalence of "tinnitus" be enough?

Comment: Thanks for the link. My understanding is that pulsatile tinnitus and the other kinds of tinnitus have [https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3719451/](quite different causes), and for that reason I think I'd need a paper that referenced the prevalence of pulsatile tinnitus specifically.